# Twitter API get list of users with a keyword in their name

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I want to get a list of twitter users with a keyword in their name, i don't think it is possible with given api.

Example: Getting a list of users with "John" in their name.

This can return: "John2782" "John Stamoss" "JohnJohn"...

Is there a way to achieve this query with twitter api? (Extra: i want to eliminate users with less than a number of followers too)

Comment: There is no Twitter API for this, no.

Comment: @AndyPiper I see, do you have a workaround for a solution for this? I just want to find users with a specific name in their name, username, bio or smt

Comment: Not really, no.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter currently doesn't have this API. As a workaround we used: https://rapidapi.com/letscrape-6bRBa3QguO5/api/social-links-search/